# Is there a way to shorten match expressions of non-Copy types using Option::and_then?

Tags: rust

The `Option::and_then` function allows simplifying this code:

```
let foo = Some(1);
let bar = match foo {
    Some(i) => Some(i + 1),
    None => None,
};
println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
```

into this:

```
let foo = Some(1);
let bar = foo.and_then(|i| Some(i + 1));
println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
```

If I try the same thing with `String`s, it doesn't compile:

```
let foo = Some("bla".to_string());
let bar = foo.and_then(|ref f| Some(f.clone()));
println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `foo`
 --> src/main.rs:4:27
  |
3 |     let bar = foo.and_then(|ref f| Some(f.clone()));
  |               --- value moved here
4 |     println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
  |                           ^^^ value used here after move
  |
  = note: move occurs because `foo` has type `std::option::Option<std::string::String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

However, the corresponding `match` expression works:

```
let foo = Some("bla".to_string());
let bar = match foo {
    Some(ref f) => Some(f.clone()),
    None => None,
};
println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
```

Is there a way to shorten this match expression like my first example with integers?

[Code on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2e6cd89e667d7e6c0dad6b9be0d0e8ab&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

- In this minimal example, I could have used `map`, but in my real code I'm calling another function that returns an `Option` so I really need `and_then`. It's just that I didn't want to over-complicate the example with an extra function that didn't affect the problem.
- I really need to use `foo` afterwards, otherwise there wouldn't be any problem (actually, `foo` is captured by a closure that I need to use more than once, and Man! did I have a hard time tracking down why the compiler kept refusing my code! The error `the trait FnMut... is not implemented for the type [closure@...]` doesn't give much indication into why it isn't).
- I used `clone` in the example because I wanted a simple operation using the string. In the real code, `foo` is not a string (it's a `Regex`) and I'm not cloning it in the closure (I'm applying it on a string and processing the results). Moreover, this code will be called a large number of times so avoiding unnecessary allocations and copies is important.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Explanation

First of all: The method you actually want to use is `map` here, since you only want to change the inner value. `and_then` is useful if you create another `Option` in the closure.

To answer your question: It's correct that you can't access `foo` anymore. If you look at the function declaration...

```
fn and_then<U, F: FnOnce(T) -> Option<U>>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
//                                        ^^^^
```

... you see that the first argument is `self`. This means that the method consumes `self` (acquires the ownership) so `foo` is moved into the method and can't be used anymore.

#### Solution

If you only need `bar` afterwards (which is usually the case), you should just print `bar`. If you really need `foo`, too, you can do this:

```
let bar = foo.as_ref().map(|s| s.clone());
```

`as_ref` creates a new `Option` that only holds a reference to the original inner variable. References are `Copy` types, so that `Option` can be safely consumed by `map`.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref):

```
fn main() {
    let foo = Some("bla".to_string());
    let bar = foo.as_ref().and_then(|f| Some(f.clone()));
    println!("Foo: {:?}", foo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just clone foo, and call `and_then` on the result.

```
let bar = foo.clone().and_then (|f| Some (f));
```

Comment: However, a clone is not necessarily cheap. If possible, other methods should be preferred here...

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: I realized with this method, I could take out the extra clone in the lambda. After doing that, don't we end up with the same number of clones as when using the `as_ref` method? Namely, one?

Comment: Absolutely true. I just thought that the `clone` inside the  lambda was just an example and OP might want to change it to something more sensible. Currently the `and_then` in your answer does nothing... :/

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt: Well I figured that too. In order to do something similar to what he was doing with his integer example, he might do something like `f + "one"`, or some other modifying operation on the string. Either way, you need to clone the String at some point. I'm just doing it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Option implements Clone which works as you would expect.

```
let foo = Some("bla".to_string());
let bar = foo.clone();
```